# How to show a Word Document in a TabItem of TabControl in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, ms-word, tabcontrol, documentviewer

Is there any way to open a Word Document in a TabItem of TabControl in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [`DocumentViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.documentviewer.aspx) control to your `TabItem` which can host fixed documents like `xps` documents. You might *need to convert* your word document to xps document and then load it into the DocumentViewer control to display it.

More information can be found in [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/viewing-word-documents-in-wpf/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems DocumentViewer cannot be converted to type System.Windows.Forms.Control when trying to add it to the TabItem's controls collection.